# Java application security permissions

Tags: java, security, permissions, uac

I have a compiled Java Application (.jar file extension, no source code) which will not function correctly without read/write permissions.  How do it get it to run with these administrator permissions?
EDIT: This is being run in Windows 7.

Comment: Read/write permissions to where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a question of Windows 7 security, rather than Java security.  Java JAR by default have full access that the OS allows.

Can you not create a shortcut and run it as administrator or start a prompt as administrator and run the jar from this prompt. If you have a service, you can set it up to run as administrator.