# Getting FileSystemException "A required privilege is not held by the client" using Files.createSymbolicLink in Play Framework

Tags: java, permissions, playframework, nio, java-7

I'm trying to use the new Java 7 [Files.createSymbolicLink()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) method within Play! Framework, and I got the following exception:

```
RuntimeException occured : java.nio.file.FileSystemException: c:\work\foo\bar:
A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

This is my first encounter with Java's permission model, so I understand what's going on, but don't yet know how to fix it (I'd like to give the Controllers more permissions).

If anyone can answer here faster than I'll find the answer, me (and future readers) will be grateful.

Comment: With Windows (W7), you can add a user to the list of who may create symbolic links (without disabling UAC) using security policies. Run "secpol.msc" and change "Security Settings|Local Policies|User Rights Assignment|Create symbolic links"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't a problem with java permissions, but a problem with the operating system permissions. See [FileSystemException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystemException.html).

The subclasses of FileSystemException are: AccessDeniedException, AtomicMoveNotSupportedException, DirectoryNotEmptyException, FileAlreadyExistsException, FileSystemLoopException, NoSuchFileException, NotDirectoryException, NotLinkException.

From AccessDeniedException:

Checked exception thrown when a file system operation is denied, typically due to a file permission or other access check.
This exception is not related to the AccessControlException or SecurityException thrown by access controllers or security managers when access to a file is denied.

Comment: BTW, when I googled for the stack trace, there were zero results on Google. So I'm the first one on the internet that had a problem with nio + UAC, and posted about it?

Comment: @ripper234 I doubt it, but you may be the first on stackoverflow.

Comment: No, seriously, I got zero results everywhere. Try it right now, you'll only find this question: http://www.google.com/search?q=RuntimeException+occured+%3A+java.nio.file.FileSystemException+%22A+required+privilege+is+not+held+by+the+client.%22#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=RuntimeException+occured+%3A+java.nio.file.FileSystemException+%22A+required+privilege+is+not+held+by+the+client.%22&pbx=1&oq=RuntimeException+occured+:+java.nio.file.FileSystemException+%22A+required+privilege+is+not+held+by+the+client.%22

Comment: It's interesting how it doesn't throw AccessDeniedException in this situation, but rather the generic FileSystemException. Kind of defeats the purpose of the specific subclass.

Answer (score 11):

After seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5132317/11236), and remembering I am running on Windows 7 with [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control), I understand this is a Windows issue.

1. Nothing can be done from within Java to make this go away.
2. I should be able to turn off UAC for Play specifically somehow (run as admin etc...), but the question isn't really related to Play (or java permissions) at all.

Indeed, when running:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
cd c:\myapp
play run
```

everything works well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217460/how-to-create-soft-symbolic-link-using-java-nio-files