# How to create Soft symbolic Link using java.nio.Files

Tags: java, windows, groovy, nio

i'm creating symbolic links on Windows using a command like this :

```
cmd /c mklink /J "${linkName.canonicalPath}" "${targetFolder.canonicalPath}"
```

From Groovy and using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method

It's working fine but i want do the same using *java.nio.Files.createSymbolicLink()* method. But I always obtain the same error message:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

The mklink /J command works for the current user and i want avoid elevate privileges

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228030/getting-filesystemexception-a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client-usi

Comment: You can also use the Java `Files` class: [`Files.createSymbolicLink( ... )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With Windows (W7), you can add a user to the list of who may create symbolic links (without disabling UAC) using security policies.

- Run `secpol.msc`
- Go to `Security Settings|Local Policies|User Rights Assignment|Create symbolic links`
- Add your user name.
- Restart your session (logoff+login, no need to restart Windows).

Comment: Thanks, it's the solution that i was looking for.

Comment: *Win10 with UAC turned off* - I had to set `Local Policies > Security Options > User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode` = `Disabled` - otherwise - same `FileSystemException: A required privilege is not held by the client`

Comment: jbang brought me here