# run a groovy script as admin from within gradle i.e. without admin command prompt

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create symbolic links. My development platform is Windows. In my groovy script I used `createSymbolicLink()` method of `java.nio.file.Files` class to accomplish this.

However, it is required (perhaps by Windows) that I run the script from within an admin command prompt, otherwise I get below exception :

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
> C:\Users\...\Desktop\SymLinkPOC\...\symlinkOfabc\abc.txt: A required
> privilege is not held by the client.
```

Is there any way I can get this script to work without needing to run it from within the administrator command prompt.

I also have a gradle task from which this script will be executed(using task type JavaExec). I can execute the gradle task successfully ,but only from within the admin command prompt.

**gradle task :**

```
task runScript (dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'myscript'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath    
}
```

Is there a way I can make the gradle task execute with admin privilege, without needing to provide admin credentials manually(by manually I mean, the script asking me to enter the credentials at the command prompt)?

If not, then is there a way to provide admin credentials(***inside the task or script or at least tell the script how to get it***) and then tell it to run ?

I can sense my requirements might be going against the best coding practices I'm not sure how to get around this.

My main concern is **how to get the script to run without any human intervention**, as this script is going to be part of the Jenkins pipeline.

Looked all over the internet, but no luck.

Let me know if I missed out on any details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228030/getting-filesystemexception-a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client-usi) help: _"...Run "secpol.msc" and change "Security Settings|Local Policies|User Rights Assignment|Create symbolic links""_

Comment: ie:  change the policy for the user jenkins is running under to allow them to create symbolic links?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Soft symbolic Link using java.nio.Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217460/how-to-create-soft-symbolic-link-using-java-nio-files)

Comment: @thokuest,@tim_yates
I came across that solution earlier. but was hesitant to try it. I always though I had admin privileges as I could run any program as administrator.

Anyways, this worked. I no longer have to run the script through admin command prompt.

Comment: for Jenkins, I haven't tried it yet.Will let you know once I am done testing it